# 256 colors in FbTerm

Tags: terminal-emacs, colors, term

Is there a way to get emacs with 256 colors in FbTerm?

I've seen some old posts on the topic but I haven't seen any confirmation that it will work.

**EDIT:**

If I start FbTerm with this command:

```
FBTERM=1 fbterm
```

... and with this in my .bashrc:

```
[ -n $FBTERM ] && export TERM=fbterm
```

(as described [here](http://homepages.see.leeds.ac.uk/~eeaol/notes/1995/01/tty-256/))

... then I get 256 colors in fbterm (confirmed by running the perl script from [here](http://www.robmeerman.co.uk/unix/256colours)) but I still only get 8 colors in emacs.

In addition, I've tried [this solution](http://osdir.com/ml/general/2011-08/msg50175.html) but with no succes.

Comment: Do other applications work with 256 colors in FbTerm?

Comment: Well have you *tried* what those posts said to do? (And link to the posts instead of just saying they exist).

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

1, Download fbterm.el

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tangxinfa/desktop/master/lisp/term/fbterm.el
```

2, Put configurations in your .emacs

```
;; 256 colors support for fbterm.
(when (string-equal (getenv "TERM") "fbterm")
  (load "path/of/fbterm.el")
  (terminal-init-fbterm))
```

3, Startup emacs with fbterm, makesure `TERM` environment variable is `fbterm`.

See [Is it possible to have 256 colors in Emacs on framebuffer-enabled tty](https://emacs-devel.gnu.narkive.com/djClHsPc/is-it-possible-to-have-256-colors-in-emacs-on-framebuffer-enabled-tty) for more information.